# Echoing element from Mt. Gox PHP API array

Tags: php, api

I am fairly new to php and have been experimenting with the mt. Gox (bitcoin exchange) API, but I do not understand the array result. Can someone explain the appropriate way to echo or print the [buy] element in php?

Thanks!

```
    Array
(
[result] => success
[data] => Array
    (

        [buy] => Array
            (
                [value] => 945.02000
                [value_int] => 94502000
                [display] => $945.02000
                [display_short] => $945.02
                [currency] => USD
            )

        [sell] => Array
            (
                [value] => 949.00000
                [value_int] => 94900000
                [display] => $949.00000
                [display_short] => $949.00
                [currency] => USD
            )

        [now] => 1389812614875071
    )
```

)

Comment: http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array name `$x`.

For example you can do this: `$x['data]['buy']['value']` to get that data.

or a [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for the buy data:

```
if( $x['result'] == "success" ) {
    foreach( $x['data']['buy'] as $key => $value ) {
        echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error occured";
}
```

You can even have a foreach in a foreach. To loop through all data in the array.